# Adding entries to context menu in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, contextmenu

I'm working on a cross-platform project which involves adding some entries to the context (right click) menu when i select any type of file/directory (and only when the program is running), so i can obtain the absolute path of the selected file/directory and doing something with it.

The solution on Windows platform seems to be using Shortcut Menu Handlers:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171(v=vs.85).aspx 
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CppShellExtContextMenuHandl-410a709a

I'm searching something like that for Linux platforms, but i still haven't found anything. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: _What_ context menu? For Windows, you're specifically talking about Shell (Explorer.EXE) context menu's on files and directories. But Linux does not have a single equivalent to Explorer.EXE.